Independence of $S$-matrix in QED of a gauge of EM field
Due to existence of several ways to fix a gauge of an EM field in QED, there are several ways to quantize it. That leads to non-uniqueness of photon propagator and hence to non-uniqueness of integrals corresponding to Feynman diagrams in perturbative calculations.
Presumably in calculations of physical interest, such as $S$-matrix, this non-uniqueness should not play a role and should cancel out in perturbative calculations.
My question is whether there is a good place to read a proof of the latter statement?

This is actually not as difficult as you think. There are schemes doing the computations that keep the gauge invariance everywhere along the way, keeping it as a free parameter. Then the results can be shown to be independent of this parameter, the implication of which is what you want. Sadly, it is a rather big undertaking to do this.

@naturallyInconsistent: Do you have a good reference?
